# Unable to dynamically set the Icon in the Tab Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, tabbar, android-tabs

I was trying to set the TabBar Icons dynamically by first downloading them from the server and then setting them as:

```
String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/HDPI/" +"dial.png";
File imgFile = new File(path);
Drawable icon = Drawable.createFromPath(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
dialer.setIndicator(getString(R.string.Keypad), icon).setContent(dialerIntent);
```

The Output that i get doing so is as followed :
[image]

I get the correct image but the size of the image gets reduced.
I don't understand why its so. I would be grateful if anyone can figure out the mistake that I make or could suggest me some new approach to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that they're reduced in the setIndicator function but we don't have the code for this fonction...

Comment: What is `ImageServices`? What is `Density`?

Comment: @CommonsWare ImageService is class having constructor with context and a string as Density. 
ImageService has a method getImage(String imageName) which returns Drawable and I am successful in receiving the image too with the correct width and height.

Comment: @CommonsWare But when I am setting that image in the setIndicator method, I get the above result.